# can't specify pip dependency in conda meta.yaml file

Tags: python, dependencies, package, anaconda, conda

I have the following meta.yaml file in order to build a conda package:

```
package:
  name: dsutils
  version: 1.0

source:
  git_rev: cat_files_bq_utils
  git_url: https://**********.git

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - pandas
    - scipy
    - numpy
    - scikit-learn ==0.17.0
    - google-api-python-client
...
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Error:  Packages/dependencies missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - dsutils 1.0 py34_0 -> google-api-python-client
  - google-api-python-client
```

But when I get rid of the google-api-python-client dependency, the package successfully builds. Please note that google-api-python-client cannot be installed via the `conda install` command line, but it can be install using pip.

My question is: how can I specify a pip dependency in a meta.yaml conda package file?

Comment: conda does not use pip. So if you want to depend on a package, you have to convert it to a conda package.

Comment: but how can I specify a pip dependency? There is surely a way ? else, I cannot fully package my code

Comment: why not just package the pip dependency as well?

Comment: seems like there's a conda recipe here: https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/tree/master/recipes/google-api-python-client

Comment: I know above comment is over 5 years old, but this conda recipe link is not there anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `conda search` doesn't show any results, the easiest thing to do is go to anaconda.org and see if some other channel might have built the package for you already.

https://anaconda.org/search?q=google-api-python-client&sort=ndownloads&sort_order=1&reverse=true

Looks like the `pandas` channel has what you need, so

```
conda config --append channels pandas
```

And then run `conda build` again.